# Why no dereference operator in char string?

Tags: c, dereference

Let's say I have 2 functions:

```
void function1(int *ptr) {
     printf("%d", *ptr);
}
```

and

```
void function2(char *str) {
     printf("%s", str);
}
```

Why does function2 work, when there is no deference operator before `str`? In `str` there is only the **address** where it points to not the **value** as I thought.

Comment: As seen [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), it expects a `char *`. Dereferencing it gives you just a char anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does function2 work, when there is no deference operator before
>   str

Because `%s`, as defined by the standard, expects a `char *`, i.e. an address.

> 7.21.6.1
>
> If no l length modiﬁer is present, the argument **shall be a pointer to
>   the initial element  of  an  array  of  character  type**. Characters 
>   from  the  array  are written  up  to  (but  not  including)  the 
>   terminating  null  character.  If the precision is speciﬁed, no more
>   than that many bytes are written. *If the precision is not speciﬁed* or is
>   greater than the size of the array, *the array shall contain a null character*.

Comment: Technically correct, but I'm not sure this helps the OP's understanding much.  If I ask "Why do we have to pay tax?", I probably want to hear "It pays for education, police, roads etc.", not "Because the government makes us".

Comment: @cnicutar I think the following two sentences from that clause should be included for completeness. (The last one is the one I find important here.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Please feel free to edit the answer as you see fit :-)

Answer (score 6):

Because a `pointer to a char` is special when using `printf`. Instead of treating it as a pointer to a single char, it treats it as a pointer to the first element in a `NUL` delimited array of chars, printing a string instead of a just a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The way you refer to a string in C is by the address of its first character.  Functions that read strings will read the byte at this address, do something with it (e.g. print it, in the case of `printf()`), and then move to the next character.  This continues until a zero byte is found, indicating the end of the string.

This is basically a way of saving memory.  Other basic data types, like `int`, are small enough that their values can be copied cheaply, so there is no need to refer to the address of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Because when we write

```
char *s="hello";
```

`s` by default takes the address of first address of first element i.e address of 'h'
and %s in the printf prints the whole string instead of element @ first location.
due to which it never requires deference operator. It might have confused the C compiler whether to print the first element or all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because the `printf()` function has been written to understand different types of arguments passed to it.  The format specifier in the string tells `printf()` what to expect each argument to be.  Then the documentation tells you what to pass to it.

**ie. basically it works because `printf()` follows a defined specification, and you're following it.**

So in your first example, you use the %d format.  `printf()` takes this to mean the argument should be an integer value.  Not a pointer to an integer, but an integer.  Which is why this works:

```
void function1(int *ptr) {
     printf("%d", *ptr);
}
```

and this doesn't:

```
void function1(int *ptr) {
     printf("%d", ptr);
}
```

**Your second example is a string and there is some possibility of confusion here as strings in C are not really a direct data types (as such).**  They are a pointer to a character which is followed by other characters and then terminates with a NULL \0.

```
void function2(char *str) {
     printf("%s", str);
}
```

Now, if strings were a data type in C, then you would probably pass them in the same way you do other values (this is purely hypothetical):

```
void function2(string str) {
     printf("%s", str);
}
```

So in summary:

```
%d -> int
%s -> char *
```